# How to get a video category android?

Tags: android, android-studio, video

I am making video sharing app in which user upload videos. How can I know users which category videos upload.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean checkRootMethod1(){
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;

    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.